# loop inside loop activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `category_aliases` table, which has `aliase` column (array type), and `category_id` column, which points to `categories` table.

I have `products` table, which has `category` column.

I have `categories` table.

I want to loop through all products (a lot), which has old categories, and map these to new categories.

So I need to check if any of `category_aliases.aliase` (`aliase` is an array of old categories) includes this `product`'s `category`, and if yes, I want to map it to new category from `categories` table.

What I tried is:

```
Product.all.each do |p|
  CategoryAlias.all.each do |ca|
    if ca.aliase.include? p.category
      p.update_column(:category, Category.find(ca.category_id).name)
    else
      p.update_column(:category, 'undefined')
    end
  end
end
```

But I am surely missing something, because even though I know, that there should almost always be a match, it updates `p.category` to `'undefined'` all the time.

Comment: In such cases, I would go for `puts/logger driven development`; add a lot of `puts` or `logger.info` statements at each step, and pinpoint exactly where the expected output is different from actual output. :-)

Comment: Is your `aliase` an array inside the database or is it done using `serialize` (i.e. a blob of YAML inside the database)?

Comment: @muistooshort  I use postgress, and store array in db (`t.text :aliase, aray: true`)

Comment: Why involve Ruby at all then? You should be able to do the whole thing inside the databases with SQL, no?

Comment: @muistooshort I 'm used to using Ruby, so would like to achieve it with that. But I'm sure you are right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to iterate through all categories ('each') in each product loop, you just need to find a matching category `detect`. 
Furthermore: if you need to iterate over many Products, is might be better to use `find_each`:

```
category_aliases = CategoryAlias.pluck(:name, :aliase)

Product.find_each do |product|
  category = category_aliases.detect { |ca| ca.aliase.include? product.category } 

  if category
    p.update_column(:category, cateory.name)
  else
    p.update_column(:category, 'undefined')
  end
end
```

Comment: even though you've mixed some columns up,the idea is clear and it works like a charm! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: hey man, if you have few more minutes, please help me out with one more thing regarding the issue. Now I changed the `products.category` column to be an array. It is done, because there could a situation, where few `ca.aliase`. include `product.category`. How would i go with erasing old product.category, and then pushing new ones? Thanks a lot!

Comment: should I simply first push new categories into product.category array and then loop through products removing first, or there are a clever solution?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment about new categories. Perhaps it is a good idea to write a new question with some code examples?

Answer (score 1):

I see number of issues in the code:

1. You updated `category` field on each iteration. It leads to update to `'undefined'` if `CategoryAlias` record does not contain category. All other iterations do not make sense then.
2. You need to break inner loop right after `category` is updated.
3. You need to update `category` to `'undefined'` in outer loop, if no alias category found in the whole `category_aliases` table.

Comment: category is a products column, so it is not a relation

Comment: I updated the answer, found a lot of issues in the code.

Comment: And, I think, that @spickermann's answer contains much better code for your case.